# How to destroy a view in Aurelia?

Tags: aurelia

So far I have tried

```
@inject(ViewSlot)
class MyViewModel {
  constructor(vs) {
    this.vs = vs;
  }
  created(owner, meView) {
    this.view = meView;
  }

  remove() {
    this.vs.removeAll(); // and some other methods in view but no luck
  }
}
```

How do I achieve this? And how do I make sure I clean up view resources properly when removing the view ?

Answer (score 1):

Aurelia provides two lifecycle methods for you to choose from on your ViewModel, `detached` and `unbind`. Typically, Aurelia will handle calling these methods, if they exist, on any view resources you utilize.

What is the reason you need to call `removeAll()` on the `ViewSlot` instance?

Comment: I was playing with a tab panel component, closable tabs. When closing, I got no idea how to destroy to component in a way that i don't have to call `element.remove()`. And when calling `view.detached()` and `view.unbind()`, i'm not sure how to unregister it from its parent. Basically I'm not sure how to release the resources properly when I want to destroy a view.

Comment: From what I can tell from your question, you don't need to do anything to "clean up" view resources. If you have resources outside of Aurelia that need to be destroyed, do that in `detached` and `unbind` as @Ashley stated.